# No funciona evento de boton asociado a datatable

Tags: jquery

Tengo un menu en el cual tengo un boton que muestra un modal con un datatable de articulos.

El caso es que me da error el DataTable, porque se ejecuta dos veces el archivo php por lo que intenta reinizializarce:

DataTables warning: table id=resultadomodala - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Entonces agregue un stopinmediatepropagation:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#artb', function(event){
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    });
```

Pero ahora me redirige al index.php y no abre el modal, sin embargo con F2 funciona perfecto:

```js
if(event.keyCode==113){ //F2
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){
           
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
        
    });
```

Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar una función 'onclick' con 'jquery' una de las posibilidades es con '.click', abreviatura de '.on('click', handler)', de este modo, modificando la función que planteabas para que su declaración sea correcta quedaría así:

```
   $('#artb').click(function(event){
          $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       });
    });
```

A continuación dejo un enlace a la documentación dónde se detalla el uso de este tipo de evento por si te resulta de utilidad: https://api.jquery.com/click/

He corregido la respuesta despues de haber repasado con mayor detenmiento la documentación sobre este evento. Espero que de este modo se pueda resolver el problema. En cualquier caso dejo un enlace a la documentación por si te resultase de ayuda: [JQuery stopPropagation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/event-stoppropagation.htm)

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo problema, lo apreto y redirige al index.php y no abre el modal, es decir si apreto F2 lo abre perfecto pero con el click sobre el boton no

Comment: He realizado un ajuste en la respuesta y dejado un enlace a la documentación, si ver todo el código es difícil interpretar el problema al 100%. Espero haberte podido ayudar. Si no es así a ver si damos con ello :).

Comment: Acabo de ver que pusiste la instruccion al final, pero de esta amnera se ejecuta dos veces la carga del modal, osea el mismo problema de reinicializacion de datatable